# How do I ensure shared assemblies are ABI/API compatible in .NET when their version changes?

Tags: c#, compatibility, static-analysis

I have a shared assembly versioned in a Nuget feed.

The versioning of this assembly is managed by manually picking a new version number, trying to guesstimate if a major, minor or patch release is needed.

As a CI step I would like to analyze if the new version of the assembly breaks compatibility with the previous one. I'm referring especially to sneaky incompatibilities that do not change the names on the API (if you recompile old code it will work against the new dll version), but change some detail, like types, that renders the old signature and the new one incompatible at the IL level.

As an example, when a method like:

```cs
public ModuleConfigurator<T> Setup<T>() where T : IModule, new()
{
    return new ModuleConfigurator<T>(this);
}
```

is changed to:

```cs
public IModuleConfigurator<T> Setup<T>() where T : IModule, new()
{
    return new ModuleConfigurator<T>(this);
}
```

with a reference to the appropriate interface, the IL compatibility is lost: a project compiled versus version 1 doesn't work on version 2. Even if the same project recompiled versus version 2 would be perfectly fine. The consuming code will look exactly alike, and a simple recompilation will be enough, but the assemblies (new version of dependency and old consuming code) will not work together anymore.

Now, if the versions are correctly identified as having breaking changes and are numbered accordingly, this is not a problem.

But they were (manually) numbered `1.1.6` and `1.2.0`.

How can I avoid this kind of problem? I would like to be able to detect this kind of problem and stop the build and release cycle, and being able to let the developer evaluate if he should rollback the change or increment the major version.

Comment: Looks like someone didn't understand what a breaking change in SemVer means (if, indeed, these packages are using SemVer).

Comment: This can not be done in a universally reliable way.  Nor does it make sense, the CLR does not pay attention to a semantic version number so incrementing accomplishes nothing.  Any tool that promises to do this should be treated like snake-oil, but some programmers like oil.  So give [this one](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=PrecisionInfinity.AutomaticVersions) a spin, its been around long enough to not completely suck.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks for the input! What I would like to do is a way to detect that some public method or property is changed in a way that renders the new assembly incompatible with the existing software targeting the old one. Ideally, this should mandate a major number update (done manually) or stop the build and throw an error of broken compatibility. In other words I don't want to automatically version the assemblies, I want just to get a warning if the public signatures changed at the IL level breaking compatibility. They are very similar tasks, but they are not the same.

Comment: It just doesn't take a special tool to do this, a compiler can already complain about it.  Make sure that, say, the unit tests are up to snuff if you want to detect this early.  What is far, far worse are the kind of semantic changes that don't alter any method signature but still break the client code.  Too many to enumerate, but say a method throwing an exception where previously it didn't.  Auto-detecting this is what takes snake-oil.

Comment: Yes, and no. Look at the example I report in my question: the code using the "old" version is absolutely identical to the code that consumes the new one. A recompilation is enough to update the dependency. Unit tests where all green. But if you try to run a dll compiled against the old version against the new one you will get a "MethodNotFound" exception from the JIT compiler. I'm trying to sniff this kind of not-so-evident problems. I should probably automate something sneaky as keeping the "old" tests from the previous version and get them running against the new version.